# How to Show Total in TextView of all items available in List

Tags: java, android

I am writing `food ordering` program, and in `CartActivity` i have to show `Grand Total` of all `items` available in `Cart`.

Here is `How` my `CartActivity` looks right now :

[image]

As you can `see` i am using a `TextView` above `ListView`, which has `0.00` as `default value`, here i want to show `Total` of all `list items`....

`Can someone help me ?` because i `believe` many of `you` already `experienced` this

**CartActivity.java:-**

```
public class CartActivity extends Activity{

    ListView listView;
    CartAdapter cartAdapter;
    TextView textGrandTotal;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        setContentView(R.layout.activity_cart);

        listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listViewCart);
        textGrandTotal = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textGrandTotal);
        cartAdapter = new CartAdapter(CartActivity.this);
        listView.setAdapter(cartAdapter);

        if(Handler.itemsHandler.size()>0)
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < Handler.itemsHandler.size(); i++) {
            }           
        }
    }

}
```

**CartAdapter.java:-**

```
public class CartAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

    // Declare Variables
    Context context;
    LayoutInflater inflater;
    HashMap<String, String> resultp = new HashMap<String, String>();

    public CartAdapter(Context context) {
        this.context = context;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return Handler.itemsHandler.size();
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int position) {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return 0;
    }

    public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

    // Declare Variables

    public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    // Declare Variables

    final ViewHolder holder;
    if(convertView==null)
    {
        holder = new ViewHolder();
        inflater = (LayoutInflater) context
                .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.adapter_cart, null);

        // Locate the TextViews in listview_item.xml
        holder.title = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.textTitle);
        holder.cost = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.textCost);
        holder.total = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.textTotal);
        holder.quantity = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.editQuantity);
        holder.add = (ImageButton) convertView.findViewById(R.id.btnAdd);
        holder.less = (ImageButton) convertView.findViewById(R.id.btnLess);

        holder.quantity.setText("1");

        holder.quantity.setEnabled(false);

        HashMap<String, String> item = new HashMap<String, String>();
        item = Handler.itemsHandler.get(position);

        // Capture position and set results to the TextViews
        holder.title.setText(item.get(ItemActivity.OBJECT_TITLE));
        holder.cost.setText(item.get(ItemActivity.OBJECT_COST));
        Log.d("Getting Handler", "Item [getting]:: " + item);

        String strValue = holder.quantity.getText().toString();
        Log.d("quantity::", strValue);
        int newValue = Integer.parseInt(strValue);
        Log.d("newValue", String.valueOf(newValue));
        String strCost = holder.cost.getText().toString();
        Log.d("cost::", strCost);
        double costValue = Double.parseDouble(strCost);
        Log.d("double::cost:-", String.valueOf(costValue));
        holder.total.setText(new DecimalFormat("##.#").format(costValue*newValue));
        String total = holder.total.getText().toString();
        Log.d("total::", total);

        ..........

        return convertView;
    }
}
```

**Handler.java:-**

```
public class Handler {

    public static ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> itemsHandler = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();

}
```

Comment: you are calculating the total cost for each item r8 add them to an arraylist , sum them up using a for loop set them in the textview

Comment: Choice of name "Hanlder" is interesting :) and surely not recommended

Comment: samosa vegetable pakora........mmmm,yummy code

Comment: Why `do` you have `sentences` like `this`? I understand `you` want to `put` them around `words` like `CartActivity` or `TextView`, but the other `words` are a bit `pointless` to put in `code-tags`...

Answer (score 0):

```
public class CartActivity extends Activity{
    ListView listView;
    CartAdapter cartAdapter;
    TextView textGrandTotal;
     double sum=0;
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        setContentView(R.layout.activity_cart);

        listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listViewCart);
        textGrandTotal = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textGrandTotal);
        cartAdapter = new CartAdapter(CartActivity.this);
        listView.setAdapter(cartAdapter);

        if(Handler.itemsHandler.size()>0)
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < Handler.itemsHandler.size(); i++) {
                 HashMap<String, String> item = new HashMap<String, String>();
                 item = Handler.itemsHandler.get(position);
                String strCost= item.get(ItemActivity.OBJECT_COST);
                //add this line of code
                String quantity= item.get(ItemActivity.OBJECT_QUANTITY);
                double costValue = Double.parseDouble(strCost*quantity);
                 sum=sum+costValue;

            }           
        }
    }

}
```

you just have to multiply (cost of each item*number of items) like above i did.

Comment: you are doing total of item cost... but i asked how to calculate grand total-- when i have total of item(s)... for more clearity see above image screen shot

Comment: i think u just a simply add one line code.see above.